# Issues cross compiling libnftnl for arm

Tags: c++, c, linux, arm, cross-compiling

libnftnl had a dependency on libmnl and I cross compiled libmnl separately for ARM. compiled libs and include dir is present in the location /home/badri/arm_libs/mnl

./configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-static=no --prefix=/home/badri/arm_libs/nftnl LIBMNL_LIBS=/home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/lib LIBMNL_CFLAGS=/home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/include LDFLAGS=-L/home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/lib LIBS=-lmnl --includedir=/home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/include

This configuration is successful. And i can see that the output of 'configure' shows that LIBMNL is present.

.

.

checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes

checking for LIBMNL... yes

checking for aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc... (cached) aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc

.

.

But when i try to do a make, I get this failure.

```
badri@badri-All-Series:~/Downloads/libnftnl-1.1.7$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/badri/Downloads/libnftnl-1.1.7'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/badri/Downloads/libnftnl-1.1.7/src'
  CC       utils.lo
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: warning: /home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/include: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       batch.lo
batch.c:11:10: fatal error: libmnl/libmnl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libmnl/libmnl.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:702: recipe for target 'batch.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [batch.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/badri/Downloads/libnftnl-1.1.7/src'
Makefile:493: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/badri/Downloads/libnftnl-1.1.7'
Makefile:399: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
badri@badri-All-Series:~/Downloads/libnftnl-1.1.7$
```

Is there anything i am missing with the configure ?

./configure --help

```
$ ./configure --help
`configure' configures libnftnl 1.1.7 to adapt to many kinds of systems.

Usage: ./configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...

To assign environment variables (e.g., CC, CFLAGS...), specify them as
VAR=VALUE.  See below for descriptions of some of the useful variables.

Defaults for the options are specified in brackets.

Configuration:
  -h, --help              display this help and exit
      --help=short        display options specific to this package
      --help=recursive    display the short help of all the included packages
  -V, --version           display version information and exit
  -q, --quiet, --silent   do not print `checking ...' messages
      --cache-file=FILE   cache test results in FILE [disabled]
  -C, --config-cache      alias for `--cache-file=config.cache'
  -n, --no-create         do not create output files
      --srcdir=DIR        find the sources in DIR [configure dir or `..']

Installation directories:
  --prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
                          [/usr/local]
  --exec-prefix=EPREFIX   install architecture-dependent files in EPREFIX
                          [PREFIX]

By default, `make install' will install all the files in
`/usr/local/bin', `/usr/local/lib' etc.  You can specify
an installation prefix other than `/usr/local' using `--prefix',
for instance `--prefix=$HOME'.

For better control, use the options below.

Fine tuning of the installation directories:
  --bindir=DIR            user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
  --sbindir=DIR           system admin executables [EPREFIX/sbin]
  --libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
  --sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
  --sharedstatedir=DIR    modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
  --localstatedir=DIR     modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]
  --runstatedir=DIR       modifiable per-process data [LOCALSTATEDIR/run]
  --libdir=DIR            object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]
  --includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]
  --oldincludedir=DIR     C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
  --datarootdir=DIR       read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
  --datadir=DIR           read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
  --infodir=DIR           info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]
  --localedir=DIR         locale-dependent data [DATAROOTDIR/locale]
  --mandir=DIR            man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]
  --docdir=DIR            documentation root [DATAROOTDIR/doc/libnftnl]
  --htmldir=DIR           html documentation [DOCDIR]
  --dvidir=DIR            dvi documentation [DOCDIR]
  --pdfdir=DIR            pdf documentation [DOCDIR]
  --psdir=DIR             ps documentation [DOCDIR]

Program names:
  --program-prefix=PREFIX            prepend PREFIX to installed program names
  --program-suffix=SUFFIX            append SUFFIX to installed program names
  --program-transform-name=PROGRAM   run sed PROGRAM on installed program names

System types:
  --build=BUILD     configure for building on BUILD [guessed]
  --host=HOST       cross-compile to build programs to run on HOST [BUILD]

Optional Features:
  --disable-option-checking  ignore unrecognized --enable/--with options
  --disable-FEATURE       do not include FEATURE (same as --enable-FEATURE=no)
  --enable-FEATURE[=ARG]  include FEATURE [ARG=yes]
  --enable-dependency-tracking
                          do not reject slow dependency extractors
  --disable-dependency-tracking
                          speeds up one-time build
  --enable-silent-rules   less verbose build output (undo: "make V=1")
  --disable-silent-rules  verbose build output (undo: "make V=0")
  --enable-static[=PKGS]  build static libraries [default=no]
  --enable-shared[=PKGS]  build shared libraries [default=yes]
  --enable-fast-install[=PKGS]
                          optimize for fast installation [default=yes]
  --disable-libtool-lock  avoid locking (might break parallel builds)

Optional Packages:
  --with-PACKAGE[=ARG]    use PACKAGE [ARG=yes]
  --without-PACKAGE       do not use PACKAGE (same as --with-PACKAGE=no)
  --with-pic[=PKGS]       try to use only PIC/non-PIC objects [default=use
                          both]
  --with-aix-soname=aix|svr4|both
                          shared library versioning (aka "SONAME") variant to
                          provide on AIX, [default=aix].
  --with-gnu-ld           assume the C compiler uses GNU ld [default=no]
  --with-sysroot[=DIR]    Search for dependent libraries within DIR (or the
                          compiler's sysroot if not specified).

Some influential environment variables:
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  PKG_CONFIG  path to pkg-config utility
  PKG_CONFIG_PATH
              directories to add to pkg-config's search path
  PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
              path overriding pkg-config's built-in search path
  LIBMNL_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for LIBMNL, overriding pkg-config
  LIBMNL_LIBS linker flags for LIBMNL, overriding pkg-config
  LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH
              User-defined run-time library search path.
  CPP         C preprocessor

Use these variables to override the choices made by `configure' or to help
it to find libraries and programs with nonstandard names/locations.

Report bugs to the package provider.
$
```

Comment: So did you compile _and install_ `libmnl` library for `aarch64-linux-gnu` target? The `checking for LIBMNL... yes` is most probably a false positive from your host libraries.

Comment: Yes kamilCuk, i did install libmnl. Since then i tried this too - 
./configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-static=no --prefix=/home/badri/arm_libs/nftnl LIBMNL_LIBS=/home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/lib LIBMNL_CFLAGS=/home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/include LDFLAGS="-L/home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/lib" LIBS=-lmnl --includedir="/home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/include" CPPFLAGS="-I/home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/include"  --libdir="/home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/libs"

Comment: With this, i get this linking error ive shown below, but make is successful. But after a make install, i don't see /home/badri/arm_libs/nftnl/include which i need. However i do see /home/badri/arm_libs/nftnl/libs. So it has been partially successful now.
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: warning: /home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/include: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       expr/redir.lo
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: warning: /home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/include: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       expr/hash.lo

Comment: so it is surely someway of using ./configure correctly.

Comment: @KamilCuk - Could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/63455706/2660143?sem=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made a new prefix path called nftnl2 and tried this.

./configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-static=no --prefix=/home/badri/arm_libs/nftnl2 LIBMNL_LIBS=/home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/lib LIBMNL_CFLAGS=/home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/include/

Now i can see both include and lib under /home/badri/arm_libs/nftnl2. So adding those extra flags must have caused some problem. It was finally only an issue with the configure.