# Issues cross compiling iptables for arm

Tags: arm, embedded, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, iptables

I am trying to cross compile iptables for ARM. I have tried versions 1.6.1 and 1.8.5 and both have similiar problems. iptables has three dependencies, libmnl, libnftnl and libnfnetlink. I have ensured all these are cross compiled and available in these locations -

```
/home/badri/arm_libs/nftnl2
/home/badri/arm_libs/mnl
/home/badri/arm_libs/nfnetlink
```

I had a similiar problem yesterday and it was related to configure. But now i feel configure is done right, but don't know what the problem is. This similiar problem can be seen here -

[Issues cross compiling libnftnl for arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63435221/issues-cross-compiling-libnftnl-for-arm/63455160#63455160)

My configure for iptables is as below -

```
./configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-static=no --prefix=/home/badri/arm_libs/iptables2 libmnl_LIBS=-L/home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/lib libmnl_CFLAGS=-I/home/badri/arm_libs/mnl/include/ libnftnl_LIBS=-L/home/badri/arm_libs/nftnl2/lib/ libnftnl_CFLAGS=-I/home/badri/arm_libs/nftnl2/include libnfnetlink_LIBS=-L/home/badri/arm_libs/nfnetlink/lib libnfnetlink_CFLAGS=-I/home/badri/arm_libs/nfnetlink/include
```

configure is successful and make results in these errors. Has anyone faced this problem ?

```
/home/badri/Downloads/iptables-1.8.5/utils/nfnl_osf.c:381: undefined reference to `nfnl_fill_hdr'
/home/badri/Downloads/iptables-1.8.5/utils/nfnl_osf.c:387: undefined reference to `nfnl_addattr_l'
/home/badri/Downloads/iptables-1.8.5/utils/nfnl_osf.c:389: undefined reference to `nfnl_query'
/home/badri/Downloads/iptables-1.8.5/utils/nfnl_osf.c:384: undefined reference to `nfnl_fill_hdr'
/home/badri/Downloads/iptables-1.8.5/utils/nfnl_osf.c:387: undefined reference to `nfnl_addattr_l'
/home/badri/Downloads/iptables-1.8.5/utils/nfnl_osf.c:389: undefined reference to `nfnl_query'
```

./configure --help looks like this.

```
badri@badri-All-Series:~/Downloads/iptables-1.6.1$ ./configure --help
`configure' configures iptables 1.6.1 to adapt to many kinds of systems.

Usage: ./configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...

To assign environment variables (e.g., CC, CFLAGS...), specify them as
VAR=VALUE.  See below for descriptions of some of the useful variables.

Defaults for the options are specified in brackets.

Configuration:
  -h, --help              display this help and exit
      --help=short        display options specific to this package
      --help=recursive    display the short help of all the included packages
  -V, --version           display version information and exit
  -q, --quiet, --silent   do not print `checking ...' messages
      --cache-file=FILE   cache test results in FILE [disabled]
  -C, --config-cache      alias for `--cache-file=config.cache'
  -n, --no-create         do not create output files
      --srcdir=DIR        find the sources in DIR [configure dir or `..']

Installation directories:
  --prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
                          [/usr/local]
  --exec-prefix=EPREFIX   install architecture-dependent files in EPREFIX
                          [PREFIX]

By default, `make install' will install all the files in
`/usr/local/bin', `/usr/local/lib' etc.  You can specify
an installation prefix other than `/usr/local' using `--prefix',
for instance `--prefix=$HOME'.

For better control, use the options below.

Fine tuning of the installation directories:
  --bindir=DIR            user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
  --sbindir=DIR           system admin executables [EPREFIX/sbin]
  --libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
  --sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
  --sharedstatedir=DIR    modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
  --localstatedir=DIR     modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]
  --libdir=DIR            object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]
  --includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]
  --oldincludedir=DIR     C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
  --datarootdir=DIR       read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
  --datadir=DIR           read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
  --infodir=DIR           info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]
  --localedir=DIR         locale-dependent data [DATAROOTDIR/locale]
  --mandir=DIR            man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]
  --docdir=DIR            documentation root [DATAROOTDIR/doc/iptables]
  --htmldir=DIR           html documentation [DOCDIR]
  --dvidir=DIR            dvi documentation [DOCDIR]
  --pdfdir=DIR            pdf documentation [DOCDIR]
  --psdir=DIR             ps documentation [DOCDIR]

Program names:
  --program-prefix=PREFIX            prepend PREFIX to installed program names
  --program-suffix=SUFFIX            append SUFFIX to installed program names
  --program-transform-name=PROGRAM   run sed PROGRAM on installed program names

System types:
  --build=BUILD     configure for building on BUILD [guessed]
  --host=HOST       cross-compile to build programs to run on HOST [BUILD]

Optional Features:
  --disable-option-checking  ignore unrecognized --enable/--with options
  --disable-FEATURE       do not include FEATURE (same as --enable-FEATURE=no)
  --enable-FEATURE[=ARG]  include FEATURE [ARG=yes]
  --enable-silent-rules   less verbose build output (undo: "make V=1")
  --disable-silent-rules  verbose build output (undo: "make V=0")
  --enable-dependency-tracking
                          do not reject slow dependency extractors
  --disable-dependency-tracking
                          speeds up one-time build
  --enable-static[=PKGS]  build static libraries [default=no]
  --enable-shared[=PKGS]  build shared libraries [default=yes]
  --enable-fast-install[=PKGS]
                          optimize for fast installation [default=yes]
  --disable-libtool-lock  avoid locking (might break parallel builds)
  --disable-ipv4          Do not build iptables
  --disable-ipv6          Do not build ip6tables
  --disable-largefile     Do not build largefile support
  --enable-devel          Install Xtables development headers
  --enable-libipq         Build and install libipq
  --enable-bpf-compiler   Build bpf compiler
  --enable-nfsynproxy     Build SYNPROXY configuration tool
  --disable-nftables      Do not build nftables compat
  --disable-connlabel     Do not build libnetfilter_conntrack

Optional Packages:
  --with-PACKAGE[=ARG]    use PACKAGE [ARG=yes]
  --without-PACKAGE       do not use PACKAGE (same as --with-PACKAGE=no)
  --with-pic[=PKGS]       try to use only PIC/non-PIC objects [default=use
                          both]
  --with-gnu-ld           assume the C compiler uses GNU ld [default=no]
  --with-sysroot=DIR Search for dependent libraries within DIR
                        (or the compiler's sysroot if not specified).
  --with-kernel=PATH      Path to kernel source/build directory
  --with-kbuild=PATH      Path to kernel build directory
                          [[/lib/modules/CURRENT/build]]
  --with-ksource=PATH     Path to kernel source directory
                          [[/lib/modules/CURRENT/source]]
  --with-xtlibdir=PATH    Path where to install Xtables extensions
                          [[LIBEXECDIR/xtables]]
  --with-pkgconfigdir=PATH
                          Path to the pkgconfig directory [[LIBDIR/pkgconfig]]

Some influential environment variables:
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CPP         C preprocessor
  PKG_CONFIG  path to pkg-config utility
  PKG_CONFIG_PATH
              directories to add to pkg-config's search path
  PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
              path overriding pkg-config's built-in search path
  libnfnetlink_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for libnfnetlink, overriding pkg-config
  libnfnetlink_LIBS
              linker flags for libnfnetlink, overriding pkg-config
  libmnl_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for libmnl, overriding pkg-config
  libmnl_LIBS linker flags for libmnl, overriding pkg-config
  libnftnl_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for libnftnl, overriding pkg-config
  libnftnl_LIBS
              linker flags for libnftnl, overriding pkg-config
  YACC        The `Yet Another Compiler Compiler' implementation to use.
              Defaults to the first program found out of: `bison -y', `byacc',
              `yacc'.
  YFLAGS      The list of arguments that will be passed by default to $YACC.
              This script will default YFLAGS to the empty string to avoid a
              default value of `-d' given by some make applications.
  libnetfilter_conntrack_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for libnetfilter_conntrack, overriding
              pkg-config
  libnetfilter_conntrack_LIBS
              linker flags for libnetfilter_conntrack, overriding pkg-config

Use these variables to override the choices made by `configure' or to help
it to find libraries and programs with nonstandard names/locations.

Report bugs to the package provider.
badri@badri-All-Series:~/Downloads/iptables-1.6.1$
```

looks like it is also expecting LDFLAGS which shouldn't be the case. If i configured alongwith the options

LDFLAGS=-L/home/badri/arm_libs/nfnetlink/lib LIBS=-lnfnetlink

I can see that it seems to get past the linker errors for nfnl. And now it gets stuck at nftnl. Although ideally i would have expected the existing configure options to suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is difficult to say what exactly is causing your issue, but I would say that you may be missing `-lnftnl` linker option - my two cents.

This being said, I tried to cross-compile `libmnl-1.0.4.tar.bz2`, `libnftnl-1.1.7.tar.bz2` and `iptables-1.8.5.tar.bz2` using the following script, and all three compilations did succeed:

`build.sh`:

```
#/bin/bash

CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-

mkdir sysroot
PREFIX=$(pwd)/sysroot

wget https://www.netfilter.org/projects/libmnl/files/libmnl-1.0.4.tar.bz2
wget https://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnftnl/files/libnftnl-1.1.7.tar.bz2
wget https://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/files/iptables-1.8.5.tar.bz2

tar jxf libmnl-1.0.4.tar.bz2
tar jxf libnftnl-1.1.7.tar.bz2
tar jxf iptables-1.8.5.tar.bz2

pushd libmnl-1.0.4
CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc ./configure  --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-static=no --prefix=${PREFIX}
make install
popd

pushd libnftnl-1.1.7
CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc LIBMNL_CFLAGS="-I${PREFIX}/include" LIBMNL_LIBS="-L${PREFIX}/lib" ./configure  --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-static=no --prefix=${PREFIX}
make install
popd

pushd iptables-1.8.5
CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc libnftnl_CFLAGS="-I${PREFIX}/include" libnftnl_LIBS="-L${PREFIX}/lib -lnftnl" ./configure  --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-static=no --prefix=${PREFIX}
make install
popd
```

After the script completed, `iptables` was available in `sysroot/sbin`:

```
ls -gG  sysroot/sbin/
total 1424
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 arptables -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 arptables-nft -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 arptables-nft-restore -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 arptables-nft-save -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 arptables-restore -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 arptables-save -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 ebtables -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 ebtables-nft -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 ebtables-nft-restore -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 ebtables-nft-save -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 ebtables-restore -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 ebtables-save -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      20 Aug 17 14:24 ip6tables -> xtables-legacy-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      14 Aug 17 14:24 ip6tables-apply -> iptables-apply
lrwxrwxrwx 1      20 Aug 17 14:24 ip6tables-legacy -> xtables-legacy-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      20 Aug 17 14:24 ip6tables-legacy-restore -> xtables-legacy-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      20 Aug 17 14:24 ip6tables-legacy-save -> xtables-legacy-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 ip6tables-nft -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 ip6tables-nft-restore -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 ip6tables-nft-save -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      20 Aug 17 14:24 ip6tables-restore -> xtables-legacy-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 ip6tables-restore-translate -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      20 Aug 17 14:24 ip6tables-save -> xtables-legacy-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 ip6tables-translate -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      20 Aug 17 14:24 iptables -> xtables-legacy-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      20 Aug 17 14:24 iptables-legacy -> xtables-legacy-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      20 Aug 17 14:24 iptables-legacy-restore -> xtables-legacy-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      20 Aug 17 14:24 iptables-legacy-save -> xtables-legacy-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 iptables-nft -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 iptables-nft-restore -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 iptables-nft-save -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      20 Aug 17 14:24 iptables-restore -> xtables-legacy-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 iptables-restore-translate -> xtables-nft-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      20 Aug 17 14:24 iptables-save -> xtables-legacy-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 iptables-translate -> xtables-nft-multi
-rwxr-xr-x 1  373064 Aug 17 14:23 xtables-legacy-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1      17 Aug 17 14:24 xtables-monitor -> xtables-nft-multi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1079440 Aug 17 14:23 xtables-nft-multi


file sysroot/sbin/xtables-nft-multi
sysroot/sbin/xtables-nft-multi: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, not stripped
```

This may help you investigating your issue or cross-compiling iptables using the procedure above.

Comment: Thanks a lot Frant. It finally worked. I took the clue from your script. It was actually - including the -lnftnl to the libnftnl_LIBS variable. libnftnl_LIBS="-L${PREFIX}/lib -lnftnl". I did the same for lmnl and lnfnetlink too.

Comment: My pleasure - we Phantom fans have to help each others.